# Spring @Transational no rollback for jdbctemplate.update(PreparedStatementCreator， KeyHolder）

Tags: spring, rollback, jdbctemplate, transactional

I'm newbie with spring framework. I used `spring.xml` to define the datasouce and `DataSourceTransactionManager`, so that I could insert data with `jdbctemplate` object.
And now I want to add the `rollback` to the transaction.
Unfortunately this `rollback` only works for `JdbcTemplate.updata` (String SQL), not for `JdbcTemplate.update`(`PreparedStatementCreator`, `Keyholder`), which I used to get the generated ID by `insert`.

```
@Override
@Transactional("txManagerTest")
public SQLQueryObjectIF process(SQLQueryObjectIF queryObj) {

    KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
    for (final String query : queryObj.getQueries()) {
        System.out.println(query);

        // Rollback works fine for the "update" below. 
        //jdbcTemplate.update(query);


        // Rollback doesn't work for the "update" below. Don't why...
        jdbcTemplate.update(new PreparedStatementCreator() {

            @Override
            public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException {
                jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection().setAutoCommit(false);
                PreparedStatement ps = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection().prepareStatement(query,Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
                return ps;
            }
        }, keyHolder);


        //log.info(keyHolder.getKeys().toString());
    }

        //just for rollback test
    if (keyHolder.toString().length()>-1){
        throw new RuntimeException("Test Error");
    }
    return queryObj;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code should be used like this (you need to use the connection given as parameter), otherwise with your code you will get a connection that Spring doesn't know about, by directly accessing the DataSource instance (if Spring doesn't know about it, it will not know to rollback in case of exception):

```
public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException {
     PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query,Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
     return ps;
}
```

Comment: Soooo nice. That is exactly what I want. Wonderful Thank you very much.~~